# Foundation 5 Upgrade: "Layer must be a document node"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to upgrade my Ruby on Rails app from Foundation 4 to the newly-released Foundation 5, and the CSS switch is going relatively smoothly. However, I'm running into a problem switching the Javascript files.

When I switch out the Foundation 4 versions of the foundation.min.js and modernizr.js files and then reload a page, I get this weird JS error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Layer must be a document node foundation.js?body=1:35
  FastClick foundation.js?body=1:35
  FastClick.attach foundation.js?body=1:35
  (anonymous function) foundation.js?body=1:40
  (anonymous function)
```

I don't even know what FastClick does, but it appears to be included in Foundation 5 and it's stopping Foundation from loading. That, in turn, is causing all of my Foundation-dependent JS to fail as well.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Note that you won't be able to reap the benefits of [Rails Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) if you move your JS into the document `<body />`. See my answer below for a better fix.

Comment: Ok, noted -- thank you! I'll move it back to the document head once the fix is incorporated into the next Foundation5 build.

Comment: It's been updated. :)

Comment: Foundation v5.0.3 has been released, so you can now use the  ̉Rails gem without any issues.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update: v5.0.3 has been released, which resolves this issue. Be sure to update your `foundation-rails` gem accordingly.

This was a bug that was resolved in [a commit](https://github.com/seantimm/foundation/commit/d98a7d540ee764e79d2dbadc0e2617964207a53c) that was [merged into v5.0.3](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/12ad42f8a5c6566df009096d6b6158b3df4e0b9d). This fix simply wraps an embedded library, `FastClick`, in jQuery's [`#ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). You can solve this by including that version manually until v5.0.3 is released.

By moving the scripts to the bottom of the page, you're giving up [Rails Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/). Turbolinks requires that JavaScript is included in the `<head />` since it wipes the `<body />` with each request.

**What's Going On**

Foundation no longer waits for the DOM to load and instead executes immediately. For increased mobile performance, Foundation 5 embeds [`FastClick`](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), a polyfill which removes click delays on browsers with touch UIs. Upon execution, Foundation immediately tries to attach `FastClick` to the `document.body`. If Foundation is initialized in the `<head />`, the body has yet to exist: `document.body` will reasonably return `null` causing [`FastClick` to crap its pants](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/5ff301160d38eb834bd1d0e2240495d273d68183/lib/fastclick.js#L88-L90).

Comment: so what do you recommend me to do to still be able to use turbolinks?

Comment: Replace `foundation.js` with [the updated version](https://github.com/seantimm/foundation/blob/d98a7d540ee764e79d2dbadc0e2617964207a53c/js/foundation/foundation.js) until the `foundation-rails` gem is bumped to v5.0.3. You could also choose to maintain your own updated version in `vendor/assets`

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to have both at the end of your `<body>` tag, not in the `<head>`.

This will throw the error:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <script src="/static/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is going to work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/static/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, if trying to include using Wordpress wp_enqueue_script hook set the $in_footer property to true.

```
wp_enqueue_script('foundation_js', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/foundation.min.js', '1.0.0', array(), true);
```